# How to get box shadow on image with using "object-fit: contain;"?

Tags: css

I would like to work with this:

```css
img {
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
  object-fit: contain;
  box-shadow: 0 0 30px red, 0 0 30px red;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b6/Felis_catus-cat_on_snow.jpg/220px-Felis_catus-cat_on_snow.jpg">
</div>
```

But the `box-shadow` should be directly on the image and not at the border of the image container. I have tried it with `drop-shadow()`, but then I can't add the effect twice. Is there any other way to fix that?

Comment: *on the border of the image and not at the border of the container* --> it's on the border of the image

Comment: I edited my question. Is it more clear now?

Comment: `width: 220px;` and `height: 147px;` please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you need

```css
body{
    display: grid;
    place-content: center;
    position: relative;
}

.container{
  width: 220px;
  height: 300px;
  display: flex;
  justify-items: center;
  align-items: center;
  border: 1px solid blue;

}

img {
  width: 220px;
  height: 147px;
  object-fit: cover;
  box-shadow: 0 0 30px red, 0 0 30px red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
      <img
        src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b6/Felis_catus-cat_on_snow.jpg/220px-Felis_catus-cat_on_snow.jpg"
      />
</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

try this:

```css
img {
      width: 200px;
      height: 300px;
      object-fit: contain;
      filter: drop-shadow(0 0 30px red) drop-shadow(0 0 30px red);
    }
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b6/Felis_catus-cat_on_snow.jpg/220px-Felis_catus-cat_on_snow.jpg">
</div>
```

You can add multiple filters but you must add them one by one.
To use drop-shadow multiple times, you have to add each shadow at its own drop-shadow.

Comment: In case it's not obvious to others reading this answer, box-shadow applies to the bounding box, but filter: drop-shadow applies to the image, itself.

Answer (score 0):

Could try something like this also.

```css
.wrapper>div {
  background-image: url('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b6/Felis_catus-cat_on_snow.jpg/220px-Felis_catus-cat_on_snow.jpg');
  height: 150px;
  width: 200px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  box-shadow: 0 0 30px red, 0 0 30px red;
}

.wrapper {
  padding: 40px 0;
  outline: dotted black 1px;
  width: fit-content
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div></div>
</div>
```